# Grails QuartZ plugin - I/O Error: Connection reset Invalid state, the Connection object is closed

Tags: hibernate, grails, quartz-scheduler

Environment - LINUX RHEL, SQL server 2008 R2, Tomcat 6

We have daily job which will retrieve data from external system using REST call and fill it in application database. Job is about to RUN for 5 to 6 hours daily. But the job is not running completely and it terminated in between at any time by throwing the following exception.

```
2014-08-21 02:58:29,557 [quartzScheduler_Worker-7] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter 
   - I/O Error: Connection reset
2014-08-21 02:58:29,558 [quartzScheduler_Worker-7] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter 
   - Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
2014-08-21 02:58:29,559 [quartzScheduler_Worker-7] INFO core.JobRunShell 
   - Job ALM.cyborg.tracking.ALMAutoSyncJob threw a JobExecutionException:
        org.quartz.JobExecutionException: Hibernate operation: could not inspect JDBC 
        autocommit mode; 
        uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; 
        SQL state [HY010]; 
        error code [0]; 
        Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.; 
        nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: 
        Invalid state, the Connection object is closed. 
        [See nested exception: 
           org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: 
           could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode; uncategorized SQLException
           for SQL [???]; 
           SQL state [HY010]; 
           error code [0]; 
           Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.; 
           nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, 
           the Connection object is closed.]
```

But there is no problem in the data base connectivity. Application is running well when this exception is being thrown. We have configured the DBCP properties well in the application `datasource.groovy`.
What could be the potential cause? Some days job running for 3 to 4 hours and for some days for an hour and it get terminated in between at any time.

Comment: Smells like two things are sometimes sharing a connection, or the connection is being forcibly closed by the pool

Comment: We have configured our connection pooling properties well.So this exception never happened when accessing the application via Browser.

This is happening only when the job invoked by quatrz plugin in the background. So my doubt is , will quartz take the application connection pooling properties or it run with its default value?

Comment: Here is my my connection pool properties.
**'
    autoReconnect=true;
    idleConnectionTestPeriod = 15
    maxIdleTime = 15
    testWhileIdle=true
    minIdle = 1
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1000 * 60 * 15
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1000 * 60 * 15
    numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
    testOnBorrow = true
    testOnReturn = true
    validationQuery = "select 1" **'
We are using MSSQL server 2008 data base.